# MySQL Workbench equivalent for OS X

Tags: macos, mysql

Is there any equivalent of MySQL Workbench for OS X? The current version is very slow and hangs up even with 8GB RAM.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) is very easy to use; both for local and remote MySQL administration.

Comment: This one is great but careful because if your username is greater than 16 characters, then it becomes unusable. https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/1886. Hope they will fix it soon. Meanwhile you can get test builds: https://sequelpro.com/test-builds

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know SQL allowed >16 characters (perusing the manuals, I guess it expanded to 32 characters in 5.7.)  Looks like MariaDB allowing 80 characters five years ago was well ahead of its time.

Answer (score 2):

I know the squelpro: http://www.sequelpro.com/

There is also the Navicate: http://www.navicat.com/

Answer (score 1):

[sqlectron](https://sqlectron.github.io/) is pretty perfect:

- runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux
- supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, and MS SQL server
- open source: https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is MySQL's corporate competitor. They do have options for Mac OS X, but I haven't used it due to my lack of owning apple devices. It is commonly used, so I'm assuming it might be another thing to try. Perhaps more lightweight as well.

http://www.postgresql.org/download/